# JavaScript Timer pauses on page reload

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I am using a JavaScript code for a timer which works fine with the code below, the only problem is when i refresh the page one second loses.

I need the timer to keep running even if i refresh the page.

I tried to get local time `setHours(00)` nothing changed.

How do I keep timer running ?

```
function work(x, id, id_p) {
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName('data-work');
   for (i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
       var totalsum = span[i].dataset.totalwork;
   }
   var Clock = {
       totalSeconds: parseInt(x),
       totalSecondsproject: parseInt(totalsum),
       start: function () {

           var self = this;
           function pad(val) {
               return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
           }
           this.interval = setInterval(function () {
               self.totalSeconds += 1;
               self.totalSecondsproject += 1;

               var hour = pad(Math.floor(self.totalSecondsproject / 3600));
               var min = pad(Math.floor(self.totalSecondsproject / 60 % 60));
               var sec = pad(parseInt(self.totalSecondsproject % 60));
               var totat_work = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
               var totat_work_db = self.totalSeconds;
               $(".totatl_hour_work").text(totat_work);
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'Post',
                   url: 'includes/function.php',
                   data: {divVal: totat_work_db, id_interview: id, id_project:id_p}
               });
           }, 1000);
       }
   };
   $('.startButton').ready(function () {
       Clock.start();
       var refresh = setInterval(function () {
           $(window).attr('location', 'agent_dashboard.php?autorefresh');
       }, 300 * 1000);
   });
}
```

Comment: put the timer start time in a session and take timer from session and compare with current time and you will get actual timer time

Comment: @Abhinav - I get time from database and save the new time every second

Comment: you can use localStorage.setItem("key", "value"); for totalSeconds and totalSecondsproject, so if you are refreshing this page last value will be there and you can continue with that value.

Comment: @Abhinav I tried it but didn't work. The problem is when I refresh it the timer counter is stopping for one second. If I refresh the page 5 times I lose 5 seconds.